# Calculating the Dot Product of two Sparse Vectors (and generating them) in Scala using the standard library

Tags: scala, dictionary, dot-product, vectormath

I am trying to calculate the dot product (scalar product) of two sparse vectors in Scala.  The code I have written is doing everything that I want it to, except when multiplying the similar elements of the two vectors, it is not accounting for the 0 values.

I expect to get 72 as my answer as 3 and 18 are the only keys that are both non-zero and they evaluate to: (3 -> 21) + (18 -> 51) = 72

I used withDefaultValue(0) hoping it would "fill in" the unmentioned key/value pairs but I do not think this is the case, and I believe this is where my problem is coming from, in the very beginning.  I think my question could also be "How to generate a Sparse Vector in Scala using the Standard Library".

If I enter the corresponding 0's and the two Maps (vectors) have the same number of key/value pairs, my code works properly.

````
```
  val Sparse1 = Map(0 -> 4, 3 -> 7, 6 -> 11, 18 -> 17).withDefaultValue(0)
  val Sparse2 = Map(1 -> 3, 3 -> 3, 11 -> 2,18 -> 3, 20 -> 6).withDefaultValue(0)
  //println(Sparse2.toSeq)//to see what it is....0's missing
  val SparseSum = (Sparse1.toSeq ++ Sparse2.toSeq).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
  //println(SparseSum)
  val productOfValues = ((Sparse1.toSeq ++ Sparse2.toSeq).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(_*_)))
  //println(productOfValues)
  var dotProduct = 0
  for ((h,i) <- productOfValues) {
    dotProduct += i
  }
  //println(dotProduct)
  //If I specify some zero values, lets see what happens:
  val Sparse3 = Map(0 -> 4, 1 -> 0, 3 -> 7, 6 -> 11, 11 -> 0, 18 -> 17, 20 -> 0).withDefaultValue(0)
  val Sparse4 = Map(0 -> 0, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 3, 6 -> 0, 11 -> 2,18 -> 3, 20 -> 6).withDefaultValue(0)
  val productOfValues2 = ((Sparse3.toSeq ++ Sparse4.toSeq).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(_*_)))
  var dotProduct2 = 0
  for ((l, m) <- productOfValues2) {
    dotProduct2 += m
  }
  println(productOfValues2)
  println(dotProduct2)//I get 72

```
````

I can create a Sparse Vector this way, and then update the values

```
  import scala.collection.mutable.Map
  val Sparse1 = Map[Int, Int]()
  for (k <- 0 to 20) {
    Sparse1 getOrElseUpdate (k, 0)
  }
  val Sparse2 = Map[Int, Int]()
  for (k <- 0 to 20) {
    Sparse2 getOrElseUpdate (k, 0)
  }
```

But I'm wondering if there is a "better" way.  More along the lines of what I tried and failed to do using "withDefaultValue(0)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using sparse vectors, you can ignore all keys that are not on both vectors.
Thus, I would compute the `intersection` between both keys sets and then perform a simple **map-reduce** to compute the dot product.

```
type SparseVector[T] = Map[Int, T]

/** Generic function for any type T that can be multiplied & summed. */
def sparseDotProduct[T: Numeric](v1: SparseVector[T], v2: SparseVector[T]): T = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._

  val commonIndexes = v1.keySet & v2.keySet

  commonIndexes
    .map(i => v1(i) * v2(i))
    .foldLeft(implicitly[Numeric[T]].zero)(_ + _)
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
// The withDefault(0) is optional now.
val sparse1 = Map(0 -> 4, 3 -> 7, 6 -> 11, 18 -> 17).withDefaultValue(0)
val sparse2 = Map(1 -> 3, 3 -> 3, 11 -> 2, 18 -> 3, 20 -> 6).withDefaultValue(0)

sparseDotProduct(sparse1, sparse2)
// res: Int = 72
```

---

#### Edit - the same method, but without context bounds & implicit syntax.

```
type SparseVector[T] = Map[Int, T]

/** Generic function for any type T that can be multiplied & summed. */
def sparseDotProduct[T](v1: SparseVector[T], v2: SparseVector[T])(implicit N: Numeric[T]): T = {      
  val commonIndexes = v1.keySet & v2.keySet

  commonIndexes
    .map(i => N.times(v1(i), v2(i)))
    .foldLeft(N.zero)((acc, element) => N.plus(acc, element))
}
```

---

#### Bonus - General approach for non-spare vectors.

One can modify the above method to work for any kind of vector, not just spare.
In this case, we would need the `union` of the keys, and take into account cases where one key does not exist on the other.

```
type MyVector[T] = Map[Int, T]

/** Generic function for any type T that can be multiplied & summed. */
def dotProduct[T: Numeric](v1: MyVector[T], v2: MyVector[T]): T = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  val zero = implicitly[Numeric[T]].zero

  val allIndexes = v1.keySet | v2.keySet

  allIndexes.map { i =>
     v1.getOrElse(
       key = i,
       default = zero
     ) * v2.getOrElse(
       key = i,
       default = zero
     )
   }.foldLeft(zero)(_ + _)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful.  I've been working through several ways to do this today and it has been a good learning experience. Im now reading up on implicits because thats the only thing I am a little foggy on here, your `val zero` [link] (https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html)

Comment: @JerryPass Ok so, [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) is a _(built-in)_ [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) that abstract over the concept of being a number an supporting basic math operations _(like addition & multiplication)_. - `def sparseDotProduct[T: Numeric]` means that the method is parametric in any type `T` that has an instance of `Numeric`, it is called [**ContextBound**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html), and it is equivalent to `def dotProduct[T](...)(implicit ev: Numeric[T])`.

Comment: Thus, this line `implicitly[Numeric[T]]` is just invoking the implicit instance of `Numeric` for the type **T** _(`ev` in the example above)_ and calling the method `zero` on it. - Basically, if **T** is inferred to be **Double** `zero` will return `0.0d`, if **Int** is inferred it will be `0` and so on. And if **T** is inferred to be something that is not a number _(that does not have an instance of `Numeric`)_ it will not compile, for example, try using a **Vector** of **Strings**. - Finally `import Numeric.Implicits._` provides other implicits that allow us to write things like `a + b`.